# What causing these red shadows in Eevee? and how to fix it?

Tags: light, eevee-render-engine, shadows

[image: picture]

Hello,

Please to meet you all, I'm a new blenderer just active 1,5 month ago and in fact this was my first time in 3D world (Covid19 made me learn this).

I got this weird issues with EEVEE render where there are some red glowing lines on its shadows, I don't think this is right, I checked my lights there are no Red Light. Even the materials that I used there are no Red color, then world environment itself is black. I'm so confused what might be the cause?

Any ideas guys/masters? (How should I address the forum?)

Thanks.

Comment: 2 things come to mind - First, are you using subsurface scattering? I think even the default color will cause red to appear through pink (like a flashlight through a hand) if you have it enabled. Second, do you have "contact shadows" enabled for your lights?

Comment: Yes, I used subsurface scattering & contact shadow on one light source. I did random tweak with these two. Yet it still happen, do you have some suggestion sir?

Comment: do you have any baked lighting in your scene i a similar problem caused by baked indirect lighting